# How can i make phone number format like 0000-0000

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to show to the user a phone number in format 0000-0000, my model is

```
[DisplayName("Phone number")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0000-0000}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Required")]
public string Phone{ set; get; } = string.Empty;
```

The view is this

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4"})
 <div class="col-md-8">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
   </div>
```

but isn't working, i'll aprecciate your help

Comment: Typically DataFormatString would be used to format a non-string type (int, date, etc) to a specific string format, not reformat an existing string.  You should do your string formatting in the View.  If you provide your razor view code then we could help.

Comment: What type of phone format is 0000-0000? Is that a part for a certain country?

Comment: Yes, it's a format for a specific country

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `regex` for your phone number format that you require:

```
[DisplayName("Phone number")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Required")]
[RegularExpression("^\d{4}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone no.")]
public string Phone{ set; get; } = string.Empty;
```

This will always ensure that your phone number is in format of `0000-0000` during validation.

To format your phone in the required format, remove the `DisplayFormat` attribute from your property and then you can use the overload for `TextBoxFor` like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone,"{0:####-####}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```